# Assume $\sum \frac{1}{a_n} < \infty$, How about $\sum \frac{1}{a_n - 1}$?

Tags: analysis, examples-counterexamples

**Problem :**

Given sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ s. t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},a_n(a_n-1)\neq 0$.

If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_n}$ converge, then how about $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_n-1}$?

---

Rewrite $$\frac{1}{a_n-1} = \frac{1}{a_n}\times \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{a_n}}$$

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a_n}$ converge, we know that $\displaystyle\frac{1}{a_n}\to 0$.

From $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-x}\approx1+x$,   $\quad\displaystyle\frac{1}{a_n-1} = \frac{1}{a_n}\times \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{a_n}}\approx\frac{1}{a_n}\times\left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)=\frac{1}{a_n}+\frac{1}{a_n^2}$

And we know both $\displaystyle\sum\frac{1}{a_n},\quad\sum\frac{1}{a_n^2}$ converge, finally $\displaystyle\sum\frac{1}{a_n-1}$ also converge.

---

Is this proof valid? if not, I wonder to know the counterexample for this one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same example given by Lorago (assuming $n>1$), notice that $\dfrac{1}{a_n(a_n-1)}$ would be positive for sufficiently large $n$ (in fact positive for every $n>1$). Specifically, $$\dfrac{1}{a_n(a_n-1)} = \dfrac{1}{n+(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{n}}.$$

Thus $\displaystyle\sum \dfrac{1}{a_n(a_n-1)} $(considering from the stage when it turns positive) is divergent by limit comparison test (compare it with $\displaystyle\sum \dfrac{1}{n})$.
Notice also that
$$\sum\left( \dfrac{1}{a_n-1} -\dfrac{1}{a_n}\right)= \sum \dfrac{1}{a_n(a_n-1)}.$$
Hence $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{a_n-1} $ must be divergent.

Answer (score 2):

(Note that this does not adress whether the given proposition is true, but merely your argument.)

Your argument fails, because you somewhere along the line assume that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n^2}$$

converges, which is not necessarily true under the given assumptions. Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ given by

$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(-1)^n}.$$

You can then easily use the alternating series test to show that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

converges. However we then also have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n^2}=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n},$$

which is just the Harmonic series, which diverges.

Comment: Oh, I can't use the inequality : $\frac{1}{a_n^2}<\frac{1}{a_n}$ unless I have $a_n > 0$.